# Do online boarding passes on Blue Air Romania need to be printed, or can one show it on the mobile phone?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, check-in

Is it absolutely necessary to print a paper copy of a boarding pass on Blue Air Romania, or is there an option to show it on a mobile phone?

What happens if online check-in is done, but the boarding pass is not printed? Is there a fee charged for getting a boarding pass at the airport, and if so what is the fee? Where is it listed?

On the [Blue Air website](https://www.blueairweb.com/), I failed to find such information.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120505/for-us-airports-is-there-really-a-difference-between-printable-boarding-passes

Comment: I strongly suspect that the only question is whether or not security/immigration would let you reach the gate. Once at the gate the boarding pass can be reprinted if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happens in practice if you don't print the boarding card, but according to [their rules](https://www.blueairweb.com/en/gb/Travel-Conditions/#6-1-ONLINE-CHECK-IN) you have to do it.

> ... passengers are supposed to print on paper their boarding pass and
>   show it at the boarding gate, border police and security check,
>   together with the rest of the necessary travel documents.
>   ....
>   The Boarding Pass is a document formed of 2 (two) pages. **One page
>   of the boarding pass will be handed to the agent at the boarding gate**,
>   the second one will remain at the passenger.

Answer (score 0):

I've travel many times with Blueair and can confirm that your boarding card will be printed free of charge at check in.